# Microphone access not working in one specific application

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone, privacy

I have a weird issue with my microphone. It is working fine in literally every app (Zoom, Discord, Audacity, FL Studio, Firefox, ...) but it somehow doesn't work in the game CS:GO. I've had this problem for over 6 months now.

I suppose it's because of the privacy protection settings in Windows 10. If you go into Settings -> Privacy -> Microphone, you can see the date at which applications have last accessed the microphone. As you can see in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kQnC.png), it says that CS:GO has last accessed the microphone in June 2020 (which is also around the time it stopped working). I have double checked the path to the .exe file and it is indeed the correct one.
Also, just for reference, Discord is detected fine as you can see in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7Orj.png).

CS:GO prints the following message on the console, which I've googled and tried to troubleshoot to no avail.

> Unable to initialize DirectSoundCapture. You won't be able to speak to other players.

Is there any way I can force allow microphone access to every win32 application or something like that?

Comment: Please try the Option 4 in the following troubleshooting article to see if the issue can be resolved: [How to Allow or Deny OS and Apps Access to Microphone in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/102647-allow-deny-os-apps-access-microphone-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: @Sunny Thanks! Unfortunately this doesn't resolve the issue. I've also tried the other options listed on the website, to no avail.

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I am having the same problem.

Comment: @zucc0nit No, I wasn't able to fix the problem. I've since installed a fresh copy of Windows 11 and that may have fixed it, but I don't really play the game anymore so I can't confirm.

Comment: @fiftyone_51 I can try to do that since this problem is driving me insane. No other fixes I can find online solve this problem.